# Edição de arquivos python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tenho a pretensão de inserir em arquivos `.py` o trecho abaixo:

```
-*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
```

precisa ser em linha específica, e em grande quantidade de arquivos.

Existe alguma ferramenta do unix/linux que permita realizar esta tarefa?

Comment: Algo pronto acho que não há, mas dá para fazer isto com o `sed` ou criar um *script* em Perl.

Comment: Procurei algo em  ` sed ` e não encontrei. Também pesquisei algo em  `awk`.

Comment: Tem que ser numa linha específica arbitrária ou precisamente na primeira linha?

Comment: Tem que ser na segunda linha. @rodorgas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para inserir essa linha, use o comando [sed](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed):

`sed -i '2i-*- encoding: utf-8 -*-' arquivo.py`

- `-i` salva as edições no próprio arquivo
- `2i` **i**nsere a string na 2ª linha

Para fazer isso em todos os arquivos python na mesma pasta, substitua `arquivo.py` por `*.py`. Você pode usar [outros caracteres curinga](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) suportados.

Comment: Estava cometendo a falha de usar uma versão antiga do `sed`. Funcionou muito bem!